# regex why aren't these two the same?

Tags: regex, grouping

```
[\w+\.]{3}
```

and

```
\w+\.\w+\.\w+\.
```

the former matches "dra"

later matches "dragon.is.awesome"

What am I not understanding right about them?

Input text looks like

i know dragon.is.awesome but

i know dragon.is.awesome.because, he is awesome

i know dragon.sucks.because, he is not awesome

i know dragon.is.dead, someone killed him

so i need to match any combination of groupings that are of the pattern \w+.

Comment: what are you trying to select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the first one is a character class.

```
[\w+/\.]
```

matches either one `\w`, or one `+` or one `/` or one literal `.`. If you want to shorten the latter, use normal parentheses:

```
(\w+\.){3}
```

Note that within character classes, most meta-characters lose their meaning. So `+` and `.` and `*` (for example) can all be contained and matched without being escaped.

Comment: Thank you grouping (\w+\.){1,5} does it. I did not know meta-characters could lose their meaning.

Answer (score 1):

`[...]` is a *character class*. It matches one character. `[\w+\.]` matches one character which is either a "word" character (letter, number, or underscore), or a plus, or a dot. `[\w+\.]{3}` matches three such characters in a row.

Answer (score 1):

`[]` is a character class, not a subpattern. `[abc]` Matches a single a, b or c.

You probably meant `(\w+\.){3}`, which *does* match the same as your second regex.